# Oracle equivalent to SQL Server DATEPART

Tags: sql, oracle, date, datepart

We need to get the HOUR out of a DATETIME column (expecting values from 0 to 23 to be returned).

Is there an Oracle equivalent of the SQL Server DATEPART function?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
 SELECT to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'HH24')) FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 29):

An alternative is the EXTRACT function which is an ANSI standard and also works on other DBMS, but it also requires the use of current_timestamp (also ANSI) instead of sysdate

```
SELECT extract(hour from current_timestamp) 
FROM dual
```

Comment: for some reason people don't like extract. but, I find it very simple and elegant.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
select to_char(current_timestamp,'HH24') from dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

for additional ways of using DATEPART kind of function in oracle

**DATEPART:-Weekday**

--This would give the day for the week for a reference start day

```
DECLARE
Start_day date:=to_date('30-03-2012','DD-MM-YYYY');
check_date DATE:=SYSDATE;
Day_of_week NUMBER;
i NUMBER;
BEGIN
i:=to_char(Start_day,'D');
day_of_week:=mod((to_char(check_date,'D') -(i-1)+7),7);
if day_of_week=0
THEN
day_of_week:=7;
end if;
dbms_output.put_line(day_of_week);
END;
```

Answer (score -1):

if you want to get the month name of a date

```sql
select to_char( 'month', sysdate())
```