# Oracle: How to get a month without year restriction?

Tags: sql, oracle

It's hard to phrase the question in a line of title, so let me rephrase it with an example.

I have a table `order` with fields `order_id`, `order_date`, etc. I want to select all orders that were placed in March, April and May in all years. So records with `order_date` of `03-MAR-09` and `18-MAY-13`, etc. should all be selected.

Is there a date function in Oracle that provides such functionality?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979261/plsql-equivalent-to-datepart this might help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select * 
from orders
where extract(month from order_date) in (3,4,5);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `Extract()` function:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE EXTRACT(month FROM order_date) BETWEEN 3 and 5;
```